# Hive partition with relational operator condition

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, bigdata, hiveql

I want to create a hive partition table with 2 partitions.
One with score less than 300 and the other greater than 300.

```
create table parttab(id int,name string) partitioned by (score int) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' stored as textfile;

load data local inpath '/data/hive/input' into table newtab partition (score<300);

load data local inpath '/data/hive/newinput' into table newtab partition (score>300);
```

But, the load data statements give error because of the ">" and "<" symbols. So, how to create partitions for this scenario?

The reason why i give this way is that because when querying
select * from parttab where score<300;
it is easy..

If I give some name for that partition for.eg:

```
load data local inpath '/data/hive/input' into table newtab partition (score='lessthan300');
```

then, while querying, i will have to remember the name of the partitions!! :(

```
select * from parttab where score='lessthan300';
```

This doesn't sound good! So, is there a better way to partition it in an elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

Hive partitions map to specific values. If you have only two partitions then having specific values for the two ranges isn't a bad compromise.

Answer (score 0):

HIVE does not support < or > in partition definition. Also hive does not store the partition column in the underlying data instead it is only held in the partition folder name. If you some how manage to achieve your said partition with < or > This will lead to data loss for SCORE field as you will not be able to get back the actual SCORE value for each record.
The suggested approach will be to keep score as is and create a new column specifically for partition which has a value of "NEW" or "OLD" based on requirement and derive this column value based on score column

```
like if(score<300) then PART = "OLD" else PART = "NEW"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

1. Load the original data into a temp table.
2. From temp table (Parttab_temp) select the data with your logic (score <300 and >300) and `INSERT` into the hive table. You will have to run the `INSERT INTO` query a couple of times based on the condition that you require.

Instead of using "load data", use `INSERT INTO`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE Parttab PARTITION1
INSERT INTO TABLE Parttab PARTITION (score)
SELECT * from Parttab_temp where score < 300; (score) 
SELECT * from Parttab_temp where score <= 300; (I have used <=33, so records containing exactly 300 are not missed).

INSERT INTO TABLE Parttab PARTITION (score)

SELECT * from Parttab_temp where score > 300;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: To find specific partition you can use hive shell to get the partitions and then extract the specific partition by using grep. This worked well for me.

```
 hive -e 'show partitions db.tablename;' | grep 202101*

 hive -e 'show partitions db.tablename partition (type='abc');' | grep 202101*
```